# Monitor host's disk usage from inside docker

Tags: linux, azure, docker

Our use case are IoT edge devices that we don't have physical access to. Also no ssh or other remote access. Only access available to us is via Azure IoT Hub.

Our software runs as docker containers on the device. The device runs Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

For performance analysis, we want to know the current disk usage (also cpu and ram) of the host and send this information periodically to our backend.

For CPU and RAM usage, I thought of using binding /proc/ to a remote monitor docker container and reading /proc/meminfo and /proc/stat.

I did not find a way to read disk usage from a "file". How do you get disk usage of the host system from within a docker container?

Best case scenario would be a solution where no additional software is needed on the host, because our only option to update/modify our software is via deploying new containers. Having software installed on the host would therefore break compatibility.

Comment: Do you own or manage the nodes, or are they provided by a third party? If it's a third party, providing shared infrastructure then it's unlikely they would give you access to the host disks directly (I would hope)

Comment: We sell the nodes to customers. So no, we don't own them. And since we cannot just get routes to many companie's shop floors, we don't have direct ssh access.
BUT are allowed to push/install new software as we need for our solution. The customers do NOT manage the nodes themselves.

For us, this functionality is about having a very basic resource monitoring for the node.